# How to put quotes between other quotes in HTML

Tags: html

```html
<p>
  <span title="This tooltip "has quotes in the middle" of it."></span>
</p>
```

I want to use `"` characters, inside enclosing `"` characters.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<p>
<span title="This tooltip "has quotes in the middle" of it."></span>
</p>
```

You can replace those quotes with a [HTML entity](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) - the HTML entity for a `"` is `&quot;`

Answer (score 5):

Use HTML character entity:

```
&quot;
```

The thing is, that some characters are reserved in HTML, and rendering engines parse them as HTML code. "`<`", for instance, denotes an opening angle bracket in HTML tag syntax; "`"`" is also an HTML syntax element, used for enclosing attribute values in the HTML element; so on. See other entities [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).

In order to use literal representation of those *reserved characters*, in your HTML code, you should use respective HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML  element indicates that the enclosed text is a short inline quotation. Most modern browsers implement this by surrounding the text in quotation marks. This element is intended for short quotations that don't require paragraph breaks; for long quotations use the  element